# BC30201 Expression expected error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

When we deploy a report SSRS generates the following error:

> Error 1   The GroupExpression expression for the tablix ‘Tablix8’ contains an error: [BC30201] Expression expected.   D:\appDirectory\Vication\AV Vication 05300\APP\7\Voilintair\Voilintair\Report2.rdlc Voilintair

when I try to make parent group for costume data in my table I get That error above?
my expression is:

```
(Fields!vic_rank.Value Like "Dda") OrElse(Fields!vic_rank.Value Like "lord")OrElse(Fields!vic_rank.Value Like "same")OrElse(Fields!vic_rank.Value Like "vatv")OrElse(Fields!vic_rank.Value Like "namert")OrElse(Fields!vic_rank.Value Like "csae")OrElse(Fields!vic_rank.Value Like "dgry")OrElse(Fields!vic_rank.Value Like "odel")OrElse(Fields!vic_rank.Value Like "sdfdf")
```

Any Help Thanks...

Comment: you are miss an `=` in the beginning of your expression for starters.. also have you tried a google search on `SSRS LIKE Expression` check out the online examples for Expressions

Comment: the equal = operator already there in my code  I will try to google it  thanks

Comment: doesn't appear to be there based on the code that you posted

Comment: sorry for that but it's there I just check it .

Comment: I am not talking about on your side of code .. I am talking about what you have posted in your question.. if you are going to post code then post full code do not omit anything .. how else is anyone supposed to understand exactly where you are going wrong..

Comment: as u can C in there no = so what u suggest ?

Comment: I suggest you do a google search on how to use the `LIKE` key word in a `SSRS Expression` good luck

Comment: ok I will Thnx for ur wishes :)

Comment: you are wasting tons of time when Google would have yielded your examples on how to do this hours ago.

Comment: Really do u think so?

Comment: Good luck in your search Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Query in my DataSet that bring the values I want instead of using expression and the query like that

```
SELECT vic_personName, vic_Type, vic_from, vic_to, Vic_days, vic_not, vic_Dep, vic_rank, ID
FROM            tbl_vication
WHERE        (vic_to BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND (vic_rank = 'Dda' OR
                         vic_rank = 'lord' OR
                         vic_rank = 'same' OR
                         vic_rank = 'vatv' OR
                         vic_rank = 'namert' OR
                         vic_rank = 'dgry' OR
                         vic_rank = 'sdfdf')
```

and the result is like what I expected with adding to date parameters to the query ... thanks

Comment: You should mark this as the accepted answer so people know the problem is solved and future searchers see how you solved it

Answer (score 0):

I got the Error **BC30201: Expression expected** in a Unit Test Solution.

Code with Error:

```
<TestMethod()>
<DeploymentItem(@"abcUnitTests\TestFiles")>
Public Overrides Sub Test01b_CreateObjectNoAccess()
```

Working Code (without the verbatim @ sign, I got from copying a C# test to VB.Net):

```
<TestMethod()>
<DeploymentItem("abcUnitTests\TestFiles")>
Public Overrides Sub Test01b_CreateObjectNoAccess()
```

If you have any attributes with @ symbols please double check them....